# Hydrogen as energy storage

Tags: hydrogen, renewable-energy, energy-storage

How viable is hydrogen as an energy storage medium? It would be extremely easy to split water into hydrogen and oxygen . It also has high energy content so relatively a large amount of energy can be stored with a small amount of hydrogen. How efficient would be hydrogen for storing energy?

Comment: More of a question for the chemistry Q&A.

Comment: Yes hydrogen is explosive but so are a lot of other things we use such as deodrants, LPG , etc.

Comment: [Electrolyis is not efficient](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms10990) neither is [generating power from it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusina_hydrogen_power_station).

Comment: This is the basis for fuel cells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hydrogen has some issues for energy storage. The biggest one is density. It isn't very dense compared to hydrocarbon fuels and compressing it costs you money. So you either have a huge tank or compressors that use up a lot of the energy your system is harvesting. It also embrittles a lot of metals so you have pipes and tanks breaking after a while. It also leaks really easily (small molecules) so pipe fitup has to be really good.

How bad is the density problem? At 700 atmospheres, hydrogen only has 1/3 the energy density of gasoline. And getting stuff compressed to that pressure is going to be costly.

Comment: The density problem makes it less useful for vehicles, but it's not such a big problem for fixed installations where you can have large storage tanks.  On the other hand, would you want to be working or living next to a huge bomb like that?  As back-up power or for short-range or low-demand vehicles (or spacecraft!) it can be useful.